# Tensorflow error when used as Docker baseimage

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, fastapi

Hi i am using below as my Docker image for fastapi application

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
```

when i run docker its running but i am getting this error

```
2021-06-23 23:31:50.516749: F tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/sampler.cc:42] Check failed: bucket_limits_[i] > bucket_limits_[i - 1] (0 vs. 10)

qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped

[2021-06-23 23:31:50 +0530] [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 2697 was terminated due to signal 6
```

and when i call api, i am not getting response, does it take time for api call or can you please tell me where it is wrong

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you are using a Mac with a M1 chip as This is a qemu bug, which is the upstream component we use for running Intel containers on M1 chips, this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5342) hasn't been solved yet. I suggest you can try and build TensorFlow for aarch64 Linux from source.

Comment: yes, how can i build Tensorflow from source?

Comment: Here are some links : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#setup_for_linux_and_macos
https://knowm.org/compiling-tensorflow-from-source-on-macos/

Comment: tf build from source is not working on my M1 and it's also not possible to run using docker. Funny